# 4 random points on sides of square are connected to form a quadrilateral, what are the mean and variance of the area of the quadrilateral?"

Tags: random-variables, expectation, area, uniform-distribution, variance

In case the description is not clear enough, here is the full question:

> "Consider a square with side length one. Choose a uniformly-distributed random point on each side independently. If the random points are connected to form a quadrilateral, what are the mean and variance of the area of the quadrilateral?"

I suppose the point on each side of the square is a uniform $(0,1)$ random variable $X_i$ wtih $i = 1,2,3,4$. So the $4$ vertices would be $p_1 = (0, X_1)$, $p_2 = (X_2, 1)$, $p_3 = (1, X_3)$, and $p_4 = (X_4, 0)$.

Does anyone see a simple, elegant solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you calculate the area in terms of $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ and $p_4$?

Comment: Hint: The area of the quadrilateral is the area of the square minus the total area of four triangles.

Comment: So I used the shoelace formula and got A = 1/2 (X2X3 + X1X4 - X2X1 - X4X3 - 1). I'm not sure if this right, because if I take the expectation using linearity and the fact that all the Xi s are independent, I get expectation of -1/2. I suppose if you take the absolute value, it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the area is $1$ minus the sum of the area of 4 complemenentary triangles:

[image: Shaded regions are complementary triangles.]

And if you write down the formula for the area of each triangle, you will find that they have the same distribution. Indeed, let $S_i$ be the area of the triangle with vertices $p_i, a_i, p_{i+1}$ (with the convention that $p_5 = p_1$). Then

\begin{align*}
S_1 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(1-X_1)X_2, &
S_2 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(1-X_2)(1-X_3), \\
S_3 &= \tfrac{1}{2}X_3(1-X_4), &
S_4 &= \tfrac{1}{2}X_1 X_4
\end{align*}

are products of two independent uniform r.v.s multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$. That is, if $U,V$ are i.i.d. and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then each $S_i$ has the same distribution as $\frac{1}{2}UV$ and hence

$$
\Bbb{E}[\text{area}]
= 1 - \Bbb{E}[S_1+S_2+S_3+S_4]
= 1 - 4\Bbb{E}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}UV\right)
= \tfrac{1}{2}$$

is the answer.

Comment: (+1) I was drawing up a picture, but you got finished first

Comment: 'Correlation between them is insignificant in our case as we will take expectation to each separately.' I find this wording a bit hand-wavey even though it is ultimately correct. The answer in all is good and shows how to go about it, but I think it could be clearer (for instance, explicitly pointing out the formulas for some triangles in terms of the $X_i$).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I agree with your point that giving the formula for those triangles would be clearer. Forgive me, however, that I wrote this answer with my iPhone in an airport and typesetting a formula with a mobile device is very painful. I will try to improve this when my flight is over.

Comment: I see, that's completely understandable.

Comment: I think instead of "insignificant" (which suggests that the correlation is small and may affect the solution but not by a lot), what you mean to say is that it is *irrelevant* (no matter whether the correlation is large or small, it makes no difference to the answer due to the linearity of expectation).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback. I edited my answer correspondingly, and hope that it reads better now.